# How to map postgres's "time without time zone" to JPA/Hibernate entity?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Current implementation:

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(name = "send_time", columnDefinition = "timestamp without time zone not null")
    private LocalTime sendTime;

    @Convert(converter=LocalTimeConverter.class)
    public LocalTime getSendTime() {
        return sendTime;
    }


    @Convert(converter=LocalTimeConverter.class)
    public void setLocalTime(LocalTime time) {
        this.sendTime = time;
    }

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp>{

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        if(zonedDateTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Timestamp.valueOf(zonedDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTime) {
        if(sqlTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return sqlTime.toLocalDateTime();
    }

}

object.setSendTime(LocalTime.of(11, 00, 00));
```

The error I get all the time:

```
ERROR: column "send_time" is of type time without time zone but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: is your access type field or propertry?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `java.sql.Time` instead. Are there a specific reason you are using `LocalDateTime`? Example with `LocalTime`:

```
@Converter
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalTime, Time> {

    @Override
    public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime localTime) {
        if(localTime == null){
            return null;
        }

        // convert LocalTime to java.sql.Time
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(Time time) {
        if(time == null){
            return null;
        }

        // convert java.sql.Time to LocalTime
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a converter. You can use annotations (as per JPA 2.2). This works with Postgres.

```
 @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
 private OffsetDateTime createdOn;
```

Instantiation can be done as per:

```
@PrePersist
private void prePersist() {
    this.createdOn = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
}
```

The example here uses OffsetDateTime but for LocalDateTime you can use

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
private LocalDateTime createdOn;
```